# Get rid of space in footer Latex

Tags: latex, footer

I want to get rid of the space between the line and the page number.

[image: Footer height]

Comment: Hi! Please provide a minimal working example ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). Also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You need to present us some code in order to find a solution for your problem as @MattAllegro suggested :)